# How to favorite user profiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application with many users, that have user profiles. I'd like to be able to Favorite a user profile, which is added to my favorites tab. I've written the below code but I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "favorites_users" does not exist
2014-02-04T02:18:56.217171+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"favorites_users"'::regcl...
                             ^
```

Right now I have the following code:

**favorite.rb**

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**favorites_controller.rb**

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :find_user

  def index
    @favorites = @user.favorites
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @user.favorites << @user
  def

  def destroy
    @favorite = @user.favorites.find_by_user_id params[:id]
    @favorite.destroy unless @favorite.blank?
  end
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = current_user
  end

end
```

**favorites.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render 'layouts/left_side' %>
  <div role="main" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="visitors-m">
      <div class="col-md-12 showing">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4><%= pluralize(@favorites.size, 'favorites') %></h4>
            <div class="col-md-3 row fr">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">SORT BY</option>
                <option value="1">General</option>
                <option value="2">News</option>
                <option value="3">Media</option>
                <option value="4">Funny</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <%#= @favorites.map(&:name).to_sentence %>


      <% @favorites.each do |favorite| %>
      <div class="col-md-12 users_info visitors">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
              <% if favorite.profile_image.present? %>
                <%= image_tag(favorite.profile_image_url(:thumb), size: '100x100') %>
              <% else %>
                <%= image_tag("people_image.jpg") %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="users_about_info">
              <h4><%= visitor.name %></h4>
              <p class="visit-time">
                <%= timeago_tag(current_user.visits.where(favorite: favorite).first.visited_at) %>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="fr">
              <p><%= favorite.address %></p>
              <p><%= favorite.age %> years old</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render 'users/visitors_filter' %>
</div>
```

**favorites migration**

```
class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

favorites_users is not a column under either favourite or users, naturally you will get that error. You need to call:

```
User.find(1).favourites
```

or

```
Favourite.find(1).users
```

Your implementation of favourites is alright assuming you have only 1 favourite ( the grammatical use of the word favourite. which unfortunately isn't widely used( most sites allow for more than 1 favourited item, or in your case, user. If the user can favourite more than 1 user profile then you need favourite relationships.

Let me know if you need help implementing that.

## EDIT

Model

```
class User <ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :favourite_relationships
has_many :favourites, through: :favourite_relationships
has_many :people_who_favourited_me, through: :favourite_relationships, foreign_key: "favourite_id"
end

class FavouriteRelationships <ActiveRecord::Base
# attributes are ( user_id and favourite_id )
belongs_to :favourite
belongs_to :user
end

class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :favourite_relationships
has_many :users, through: :favourite_relationships
end
```

Kindly pass the user id as the current user id and the favourite id as the parameters to create a favourite.

```
<% form_for Favourite.new do |f| %> 
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
etc....
```

and create the favourite with that form.

Comment: Wow thanks so much Sherwyn that makes sense, and yes I'd need some help implementing that, as users would be able to favorite many user profiles. Would you mind please showing how the controller, model and view code should look?

Comment: controller will be a simple create action with a redirect

Comment: That's great, thanks again! How would it work with the button? I.e.A user click's 'Favorite this profile' button, not quite sure how that would work.

Comment: the button will be styled according to your desired "favourite button" styling, and clicking it will submit a form to the favourite controller to create a favourite object storing the id of the current user and the id of the favourited user, similar to what you get with a basic scaffold.

Comment: Got it, but I wasn't referring to the styling but more or less the actual code. I'm guessing it would be something like <%= link_to 'Mark as favorite', favorite_create_action %>. Please help clear this up for me, and thanks so much for your help. Once u answer that I will accept your answer.